# having a nonetype data with "get" or "post" method while using a super simple <form>

Tags: python, html, cgi

When I use getvalue() method in cgi.fieldstorage() class, I have the variable "name" in nonetype. Simply I cannot do anything with the value obtained from the form. I cannot calculate the result and cannot edit the result. But it can be shown on the html. How can i make use of the variable by getting rid of the nonetype?

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

test1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test1</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/test2.py" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">  <br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

test2.py:

```
import cgi, cgitb 

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

your_name = form.getvalue('name')
your_name = 'hello, '+ your_name 

print('Content-type:text/html')
print()
print('<html>')
print ('<head>')
print ('<title>CGI</title>')
print ('</head>')
print ('<body>')
print(your_name)
print ('</body>')
print ('</html>')
```

Comment: why the php tag?

Comment: pressed by mistake sorry:)

Comment: you can edit...

Comment: sorry for being so silly cuz im new to stackoverflow and this is my first question:(